# Is there any easy way to obfuscate an Android app when using IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, obfuscation

I searched on google and stackoverflow and found the way to obfuscate is either writing an ANT script or change to Eclipse.And with the version of 12,does intellij idea have some easy way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IntelliJ IDEA has a way, but it's not likely to be an "easy way".

On one hand, the IntelliJ Documentation [says](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/generating-a-signed-apk-through-an-artifact.html):

> **Generating a Signed APK Through an Artifact**
>
> [...]
>
> Step 8. To have IntelliJ IDEA [obfuscate the application](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/07/optimizing-obfuscating-and-shrinking.html) during packaging,
>   select the Run ProGuard check box and specify the location of the
>   proguard.txt configuration file. The file is generated during project
>   creation and is stored in the project root. IntelliJ IDEA suggests
>   this default location in the Config file path text box. Accept the
>   suggestion or specify a custom configuration file by clicking the
>   Browse button  and selecting the required file in the dialog that
>   opens.

but on the other hand, the link labeled "obfuscate the application" leads you to an [external blog post](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/07/optimizing-obfuscating-and-shrinking.html) that talks about using an ant script to obfuscate your code.

And if the comment two months ago at the bottom of that documentation page left by a developer is representative, the official instructions given by IntelliJ don't even seem to work properly in his case. So I'm guessing that's why they're still linking to an external blog post that talks about doing it a different way. Besides if their instructions truly worked, they really wouldn't need to link to an external page that talks about that.

Comment: Thank you very much.Maybe in Android Studio it will be fun :).

Answer (score 1):

I always Go with ANT. Helps me build android easily on my IDE less AWS instance. 
But for IntelliJ 12.0.1 - official [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/generating-a-signed-apk-through-an-artifact.html):

> To have IntelliJ IDEA obfuscate the application during packaging,
>   select the Run ProGuard check box and specify the location of the
>   proguard.txt configuration file. The file is generated during project
>   creation and is stored in the project root. IntelliJ IDEA suggests
>   this default location in the Config file path text box. Accept the
>   suggestion or specify a custom configuration file by clicking the
>   Browse button  and selecting the required file in the dialog that
>   opens.

Although the page the above script came from refers to an external link: http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/07/optimizing-obfuscating-and-shrinking.html
which talks about Ant.

Comment: Thank you very much.Maybe in Android Studio it will be fun :).